# Scraping HTML (or JavaScript) Table

Tags: javascript, html, r, web-scraping, html-table

I'm trying to scrap a table on a website, but can't succeed... I've already done that numerous time, it always worked, but since time the table seems to be in some sort of a Javascript, and the parsing doesn't work at all? Can someone help me?

The page is [here](http://www.whoscored.com/Matches/411429/LiveStatistics/England-Premier-League-2010-2011-Fulham-Arsenal).

I already tried the usual:

```
readHTMLTable(doc//table[@id='live-player-home-offensive-grid'], as.data.frame=TRUE, header=FALSE)
# or
xpathSApply(pagetree, "//*/table[@id='live-player-home-offensive-grid']", xmlValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the data is not in the table, but in the Javascript code --
it is only put in the table when the page is rendered, in your browser.

I do not see a clean way of extracting it,
short of using Javacript tools or web browser controllers
([Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/),
[CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/),
[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/),
[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)).

The following reads the HTML page as a string,
and looks for the definition of the `initialData` variable,
that apparently contains the data.
It returns the data in the same hard-to-use format,
a list of lists of lists of lists of lists of lists of lists.

```
library(RCurl)
url <- "http://www.whoscored.com/Matches/411429/LiveStatistics/England-Premier-League-2010-2011-Fulham-Arsenal"
html <- getURL(url)
initial_data <- gsub("^.*?initialData = (.*?);.*", "\\1", html)
initial_data <- gsub("'", '"', initial_data)
library(RJSONIO)
data <- fromJSON( initial_data )
```

Comment: Actually, that's quite helpful ! From that point, I can unlist the data, and I'm left with a quite long vector containing all the data I want. From that, I put it into data.frame, and I have a 1 column, 5k+ lines dataframe. ANd that's almost done, if some one can help me do that : how do I tell R how many col I want when converting into data.frame? I didn't succeed with a "ncol". Again, thank you very much !

Comment: The problem is that those lists are deeply nested, and do not have the same length.
You can try to understand the structure of the data by looking at `cat(toJSON(data))`, 
`cat(toJSON(data[[1]]))`, 
`cat(toJSON(data[[1]][[1]]))`, etc.
The following seems to be meaningful and easy to use,
but I may have discarded too much data:
`lapply( data[[1]][[2]][[1]][[5]], function(u) c( "name", u[[2]], unlist( u[[4]] ) ) )`.